# What hidden services does my relay node know about?

Tags: relays, directory, source-code

I built tor from source and am running it as a relay (not exit node) and also as a directory server.  It is my understanding that after a while I should experience V2 hidden services publishing their descriptors to me (each hidden service picks 6 directory servers at random to publish their descriptor to).  How can I tell if this is happening? Can I (temporarily, for debugging purposes) view the descriptors being published to me?

I'm thinking their might be some useful logging if I enable debug logs (but I can't find it)?  Or maybe there is something I can get over the control protocol (but I couldn't find anything obvious in the stem API docs that exposes it)?  Or maybe I could make a code change to log this information (I'm not sure where the code is that receives the announcements)?

Answer (score 0):

[Nyx](https://nyx.torproject.org/) is probably the utility that you are looking for to provide that information.

Comment: Cool tool, but I don't see anything there for viewing hidden service descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

https://rp.os3.nl/2017-2018/p98/report.pdf

You can extract descriptors!

It works well...100%